# need help understanding what this code does line by line

Tags: jupyter-lab

```
import random

random_numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for r in range(10)]

print(random_numbers)

for i in range(len(random_numbers)):
    min_index = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(random_numbers)):
        if random_numbers[min_index] > random_numbers[j]:
            min_index = j

    random_numbers[i], random_numbers[min_index] = random_numbers[min_index], random_numbers[i]
print(random_numbers)
```

i struggle to completly understand this code, and some help whould be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a list of random numbers and then sorts them, from lowest to highest.

When you're a little more used to coding you'll be able to use a debugger to see how these changes work. Until then, the best thing to do load the thing up with print statements, and see how you go.

We'll do three little cheats first though.

1. We'll choose random numbers from 1 to 10 instead of 1 to 100.
2. We'll  have a list of four elements, rather than ten. These changes make things more managable to when you're trying to figure out how things work.
3. We're going to create a dummy variable, `_`, and set it to `_ = input()`. This means you have to hit a key on every iteration of the code, so you can control what's happen. Just hit return each time the prompt comes up, and that'll move you on to the next iteration of the loop.

OK, here we go. First, we create our list of random numbers and get a look at them.

```py
random_numbers = [random.randint(1,10) for r in range(4)]

print(random_numbers)
```

Next we have two loops - an outer loop, and an inner.

```py
for i in range(len(random_numbers)):
    min_index = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(random_numbers)):
        print(f"i: {i}, j: {j}")
```

When the `i` loop starts, the `min_Index` variable to set to whatever the `i` value is, and the `j` is set to `i+1`. So first time out, `i=0`, `min_index=0`, and `j=1`. We'll print those to the screen, so we always know where we are.

Every time the `j` loop runs, it compares the value at `random_numbers[min_index]` to the value at `random_numbers[j]`. We're printing those values.

```py
print(f"The random number at min_index {min_index} is {random_numbers[min_index]}.")
print(f"random number at j {j} is {random_numbers[j]}.")
```

On every run of the inner, `j`, loop, we check to see if `random_numbers[min_index] > random_numbers[j]`. If it is, we change `min_index` to `j`, If it isn't, we just roll along.

Now. At the end of the that `j` loop, we swap the values of   `random_numbers[i]` and `random_numbers[min_index]` . That awkward-looking `random_numbers[i], random_numbers[min_index] = random_numbers[min_index], random_numbers[i]` is syntactic sugar. If we didn't use it, we'd have to use a third, temporary variable, like this:

```py
temp = random_numbers[i]
random_numbers[i] = random_numbers[min_index]
random_numbers[min_index] = temp
```

So `a, b = b, a` just means "swap a and b's values."

Now, if  `random_numbers[min_index] > random_numbers[j]` was true, those values swap around. If it wasn't, nothing happens because `min_index` and `j` are the same - we're saying `a, b = a, b`.

As the outer loop rolls along, the lower values are progressively moved along to the front of the the list until, by the end of the loop, all the random numbers are sorted. I know this seems very verbose, but it'll make more sense when you run the full code:

```py
for i in range(len(random_numbers)):
    min_index = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(random_numbers)):
        print(f"\ni: {i}, j: {j}, min_index: {min_index}.")
        print(f"The random number at min_index {min_index} is {random_numbers[min_index]}.")
        print(f"random number at j {j} is {random_numbers[j]}.")
        if random_numbers[min_index] > random_numbers[j]:
            print(f"Because {random_numbers[min_index]} is greater than {random_numbers[j]} I'm going to set the min_index value to j")
            min_index = j
            
        _ = input() # pause button
        
    print("And that's the end of inner loop.")

    print("random numbers[i] was", random_numbers[i])
    print("random numbers[min_index] was", random_numbers[min_index])

    random_numbers[i], random_numbers[min_index] = random_numbers[min_index], random_numbers[i]
    print("random numbers[i] is", random_numbers[i])
    print("random numbers[min_index] is", random_numbers[min_index])

print(random_numbers)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm glad it's of some use. You should check out https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit - it's great for seeing how code steps through things. It doesn't use imports, but if you paste in the the code above, cut out the `print` and `input` statements, and set `random_numbers` to a list, `[4,1,2,3]`, or whatever, I'm sure that'll help too.